# Matlab how do I sort my data?

Tags: matlab, sorting

I am trying to sort mydata:

```
mydata = 

  Columns 1 through 3

  [11512x2 double]    [17330x2 double]    [15044x2 double]
```

I want to sort it (ascending order) by length(mydata(1)), length(mydata(2)) and length(mydata(3)),

so, after the sorting I have to get:

```
mydata = 

  Columns 1 through 3

  [11512x2 double]     [15044x2 double]     [17330x2 double]
```

If it was a struct, I could do:

```
[blah, order] = sort([mydata(:).Area],'ascend');
```

and then:

```
sortedStruct = mydata(order);
mydata = sortedStruct;
```

but it doesn't..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the length vector , sort it and use the index:

```
  l = cellfun(@length ,mydata);
  [unused,order] = sort(l);
  sortedStruct = mydata(order);
```